# How to INSERT & Symbol in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm inserting a CSV File into a MySQL Table. One row of the CSV file has a name with & Symbol like this:

```
Peter & Peter
```

Shortly befor the Database Insert, the echo-statement of $Variable gives "Peter & Peter" and until here, String looks fine. 
But after the Insert, Database shows:

```
Peter &amp; Peter
```

How can I INSERT "&"-Symbol into Database?

After Database Connection, I indicate all possible settings to UTF8:

```
# Database Connection here
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$charset = $mysqli->character_set_name();
printf ("Current character set is %s\n", $charset);
```

Database parameters:

- Current character set is utf8
- Column type is varchar(200)
- The DB-Table is "utf8_general_ci" and
- all Fields of the Table are also set to Collation "utf8_general_ci"

How can I INSERT "&"-Symbol into Database?

Comment: Do you use `htmlspecialchars()` going in? Such a function should only be used for *output*, not input.

Comment: MySQL doesn't care about `&` so unless you're doing something really odd in your insert this is not an issue. As Qirel points out, **do not** use `htmlspecialcars` on inserting. That does not properly escape your data, it only mangles it. If you can, edit to show your insertion code as I have a feeling you're not using prepared statement with placeholder values. That *will* fix your problem.

Comment: when you echo inside of an html page, &amp; gets translated to & by the browser - thus the &amp; was likely there all along long before you noticed it.

Comment: @Calimero No it doesn't. This is talking about what's in the database, the browser isn't a factor.

Comment: `&` is not a special character for MySQL. Use it the same as other regular character (`A`, for example). Make sure you **do not** `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` the text you don't display as HTML (insertion into the database does not require generation of HTML).

Comment: @tadman it ends up in the database because it was there before inserting, and the php echo statement (in html context) did not allow OP to diagnose the problem correctly. The problem has actually nothing to do with the database at all, since there is nothing special about inserting a "&" in mysql as we both know.

Comment: @calimero PHP's `echo` statement absolutely does not HTML encode anything. This is a source of a lot of security problems in the PHP world.

Comment: @tadman echo doesn't but the *browser* translates the *entities* such as *&amp;*. Thus trying to debug with an echo here was a bad call which led to wrong conclusions.

Comment: @Calimero I'm going to interpret "the database shows" literally, as in `&amp;` is in the database, unless told otherwise. In that case the browser is not a factor. Additionally, if you echo `&` then you will get *literally* that in the browser, no translation. This is easily tested with a minimal HTML file and "View Source..."

Comment: "How can I INSERT "&"-Symbol into Database?" (ampersand is it's name)
 Like this: http://rextester.com/NEYBY10005 `Insert into SOQ46058921 values ('This is a test of & insert');` works fine.  Perhaps you're looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: If I had to guess the value is being posted in and you're accessing the value from the query string which is showing it as Peter&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Peter and for some unknown reason the name' when requested from the query string isn't getting set back to the correct value.

Comment: @axiac: Thank you very much for your hint: "htmlentities" causes this issue. Problem solved.

Comment: Also Thanks to @xQbert. The direct INSERT INTO was helpful in solving this issue.

Comment: @Peter I know I need proof something works sometimes before I'll believe it's not the problem.  "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth"

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO (field) VALUES ('&');